# Detect Screen Touches on the iOS while in Background

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, touch, background-process

I am doing some work to hopefully monitor when an iOS device (non-jailbroken) is in use in some fashion.

The current technique I am hoping to detect is detecting a screen touch event has occured. Note that I don't require information about where the screen was touched, or how long. Just that it was touched.

I was hoping to maybe detect some sort of "idle" mode of the device.

I currently log for the unlock event of the phone, but phones with no auto-lock will stay with the screen on, even while there is no "activity" happening to it, so that is an imperfect solution at the moment for tracking "active" usage of the phone.

Note that I am going to have this be running while in the background.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try one of these functions:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        code
    }

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    code
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    code
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    code
}

override func touchesEstimatedPropertiesUpdated(touches: Set<NSObject>) {
    code
}
```

Comment: Sadly, that only works when the application is in the foreground.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry :/